# Paypal Sandbox- going to a live production environment

Tags: api, testing, live, paypal-sandbox, woocommerce

I have a new WP, woo-commerce site with paypal express plugin. I have added my paypal API credentials (not sandbox credentials) and am set to Live-Production mode but am still being directed to Paypal Sandbox when checking out. How do I get out of the testing environment on my site

Answer (score 1):

change the occurrence of https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr into https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

Answer (score 0):

Below are steps to change environment on **PayPal express plugin** from wordpress admin panel.

1- In your admin panel go to **WooCommerce > Settings > Checkout.**
2- Enter the following information to complete your **WooCommerce Express Checkout** configurations:
Enable PayPal express checkout by **Click the box**.
Environment - **Set to Live** unless testing with PayPal sandbox environment credentials.
Enable PayPal mark - **Check**.
PayPal API Username - Write your **Live API username**.
PayPal API Password - Write your **Live API password**.
PayPal API Signature - Write your **Live API Signature**.
Payment Action - Select from dropdown **Sale or Authorize**.
Check additional options.